# How to getSource from a button object made from other class'

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

i am making a memory game using java swing. so far i have made a class that returns custom JButtons with an image already in them (unfliped). in the main class i am creating objects of that class and add them to the panel. everything works but when i am adding the action listeners the getSource method returns a JButton and as a result i cant use the methods from inside the custom buttons class. How can i use getSource and create a button from the custom buttons class?

i have tried casting the button returned from the getSource method to Buttons(custom buttons class) but it didnt work.

```
public class Buttons extends JButton{
    int id;
    JButton butt;
    private static int x=0;

    public Buttons() throws IOException{
        butt=this.retButton();
    }

    public JButton retButton() throws IOException{
        BufferedImage img = 
        ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/folder/flipped.png"));
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(img);
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setName(Integer.toString(x));
        button.setIcon(image);
        button.setBackground(Color.white);
        x+=1;
        return button;

    }
    public JButton getButton(){
        return this.butt;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
   }
}
```

in the main class i am using:

```
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
        jb[i] = new Buttons();
        jb[i].getButton().addActionListener(this);
        jb[i].setId(cardNums.get(i));
        panel.add(jb[i].getButton());
    }

    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton)source;
        System.out.println("hey");}
```

action listener works but since btn is a JButton it wont let me use the getId method of the Buttons class.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want your Buttons instance to have a separate button as an attribute? You already ARE a button. This seems like a poor design choice.

That said, since you set the button name to be the creation index,you could just use `source.getName()` and convert it back to an int, then use that int as an index for the jb array.

Comment: excuse me if i am being a little noob but i dont have much experience :/ the reason why i am not using the getName is because the name is the index of the imageicon that is going to go on the card when flipped. so button 0 gets the "imageicon[0]" the reason why i am trying to use the getId method is because every button gets the id(key) of the card. ex buttons 1 and 5 have different names but the same id since they have the same card when flipped. i need the ids to compare the flipped cards :/ also i have a getStatus method that returns boolean and checks if the card is matched already or not